# Clear cache in MS Project Standard 2019

Tags: ms-project

MS Project Professional allows you to do cache clearing, but is there a way to do cache clearing in MS Project Standard? If MS Project Standard does not provide this possibility from the menus is it possible to do it differently?
This is because I've an Add-in which apparently is able to save few data inside MS Project. Restart MS Project doesn't allow me to clear such a date, so I suppose some information is cached somewhere.

Comment: I believe clearing cache in MS Project is only useful for MS Project Server users or MS Project Online users, neither of which use MS Project Standard. Can you explain why you want to clear the cache?

Comment: Considering it's a functionality related to the add-in, it's unlikely that you'll get an answer elsewhere but the add-in related community.